# Problem connecting to Microsoft PPTP VPN using Kvpnc

Tags: connection, vpn, opensuse

Using OpenSuse and kvpnc, I'm unable to connect to a windows PPTP VPN.

I selected PPTP for type of the connection, and entered the username, password and the gateway address. All other options are left to default.

The connection fails every time.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: why vote down when it is a problem! I really really need a help!

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Comment: is there any tag about programming there that you voted me down?

Comment: See the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: This is not for serverfault either, it belongs to superuser. I do not see how this is related to server administration at all.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information provided, the only option is to guess. Check this tutorial to see if it helps: http://vimalkumar.in/2008/09/19/howto-connect-to-a-pptp-vpn-server-using-kvpnc/

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, switching to MSCHAP (v1) helps - Settings -> Profile -> Connection specific -> PPTP -> Authentication -> change Method from MSCHAP-v2 to MSCHAP